# Understanding WFS Metadata

Tags: wfs

I get the concept of what a WFS is supposed to accomplish and how it does it however I can't seem to find any clear insight into how it handles feature metadata. GeoJSON has a properties attribute for any extra data you want to include with the feature is there something similar with WFS?

Answer (score 1):

With a WFS, the GetCapabilities response may provide some metadata, not only about the service itself but also specifically about the data served.

[Example WFS GetCapabilities request](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&)

For example in this above response we can see that each of the FeatureTypes has an associated metadata link such as:

```
<FeatureType>
<Name>UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS</Name>
...
<MetadataURL format="text/xml" type="TC211">
http://metadata.bgs.ac.uk/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?service=CSW&request=GetRecordById&elementSetName=full&OutputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&ID=9df8df52-d786-37a8-e044-0003ba9b0d98&
</MetadataURL>
</FeatureType>
```

To find out more about the FeatureType itself you can make a DescribeFeatureType request like:

[Example WFS DescribeFeatureType request](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&TypeName=UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS&version=1.1.0&)